# Is there a way to know the SQL Always On Cluster name in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, alwayson

I have a SQL Server Always On cluster set up. The cluster name is:

```
DBCLUSTER001.mydomain.net
```

It has a few nodes (virtual servers) for fail overs.

Let's say they are:

```
Node1,
Node2, etc...
```

To know which node is currently active I run this

```
SELECT activeServer = @@SERVERNAME;
-- Let's say, it resulted in 'Node1'
```

What I'm trying to find out that is there a SQL command or query that I can run from the current active node (Node1) to get the cluster name?

It's like if there is something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM <something; a function, table, command> 
--my expected output is: DBCLUSTER001.mydomain.net
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

I am looking in to the [SQL Server Operating System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-cluster-nodes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) queries, but so far they all are giving me the Node info only.

Is getting the cluster name actually possible?

I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Try the system table `sys.availability_groups_cluster`

Comment: anythin in sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Charlieface, @JonTout, Unfortunately it turned out that the service user credential which the application uses in the prod and other non prod environments does not and will not have the necessary permission, i.e, `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission. So the query won't be able to run by the service user anyway.
I will try to find it out a different way, may be in my case I have to use some hard coding.

Comment: Put it into a stored procedure, and sign the procedure with a certificate of a user that has `sa` permissions. Then give this service user permission to run the procedure